# MATLAB writing to serial in Arduino slow

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-port, communication

I want to send commands from MATLAB to Arduino through serial, but I'm facing some problems. I have a stepper motor which it needs to be rotated left and right and should check for sensor whether it reaches the position that it should.

MATLAB connecting code:

```
function arduino = conn()
    arduino = serial('COM4','BaudRate', 19200);
    fopen(arduino);
    pause(3);
end
```

and Arduino:

```
int pin = 2;
int pinValue;
int pinHuman = 3;
const int stepPin = A5; 
const int dirPin = A4; 
int readV;
int valueHuman;
int tim = 10000;
String vl1 = "";
String vl2 = "";
String vl = "";

void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(19200);
   Serial.setTimeout(10);
   pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT); 
   pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(pin,INPUT_PULLUP);
   pinMode(pinHuman,INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() 
{
   valueHuman= digitalRead(pinHuman);
   pinValue= digitalRead(pin); 
   vl1 = (String)valueHuman;
   vl2 = (String)pinValue;
   vl = "2" +vl1 + "" + vl2 + "3";
   Serial.println(vl);
   if (Serial.available() > 0) 
   {   
       readV= Serial.read();  
       if(readV== 48)
       {
           digitalWrite(dirPin,1);
           rotateBase();  
           rotate(1);   
       }
       if(readV== 49)
       {
           digitalWrite(dirPin,0);
           rotateBase();  
           rotate(0); 
       }
   }  
}

void rotate(int d)
{
    pinValue= digitalRead(pin);  
    while(pinValue== 0)
    {        
        pinValue= digitalRead(pin);   
        digitalWrite(dirPin,d); 
        digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
        delay(5); 
        digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);   
        delay(5);
        pinValue= digitalRead(pin); 
        vl2 = (String)pinValue;
        vl = "2" +vl1 + "" + vl2 + "3";
        Serial.println(vl);
    }  
}

void rotateBase()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<120; i++)
    {
        digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
        delayMicroseconds(tim); 
        tim = tim - 32;
        digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);   
        delayMicroseconds(tim);        
        tim = tim - 32;
        pinValue= digitalRead(pin); 
        vl2 = (String)pinValue;
        vl = "2" +vl1 + "" + vl2 + "3";
        Serial.println(vl);
    }
    delayMicroseconds(tim-10);
    for(int i = 0; i<560; i++)
    {
        digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
        delayMicroseconds(2300); 
        digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);   
        delayMicroseconds(2300);
        pinValue= digitalRead(pin); 
        vl2 = (String)pinValue;
        vl = "2" +vl1 + "" + vl2 + "3";
        Serial.println(vl);
    }
    delayMicroseconds(tim-10);
    for(int i = 0; i<120; i++)
    {
        digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
        delayMicroseconds(tim); 
        tim = tim + 32;
        digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);   
        delayMicroseconds(tim);        
        tim = tim + 32;
        pinValue= digitalRead(pin); 
        vl2 = (String)pinValue;
        vl = "2" +vl1 + "" + vl2 + "3";
        Serial.println(vl);
    }  
    tim = 10000; 
}
```

To write to Arduino through serial from MALAB:

```
function rotateBase(arduino,d)
    sensors = [0,0];
    fprintf(arduino,'%i',d);
    pause(1)
    readR = native2unicode(fread(arduino));
    while sensors(2)~= 1
        sensors =decodeMessage(readR); //decodeMessage(array) updates sensors array based on arduino output
        readR = native2unicode(fread(arduino));
    end
end
```

So if i create arduino connection:

```
arduino = conn;
```

and if i try to communicate:

```
rotateBase(arduino,0);
```

the motor starts to rotate 3-5 seconds after the command

```
fprintf(arduino,'%i',d);
```

is executed. I cant solve this delay problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `delay(3)` in MATLAB?

Comment: Also, have you tried limiting the communication to the minimum? you have a lot of Serial writes, the may be delaying the rest of the code

Comment: It's a long shot... try to put all `Serial.println(vl);` in comment. Also try to put all code lines before `if (Serial.available() > 0)` in comment.

Comment: Also, in Matlab code, try: `fwrite(arduino, uint8(48));` instead of `fprintf(arduino,'%i',d);`

Comment: @AnderBiguri delay(3) its because while searching for solution, some suggestions were to add delay before and after writing commands to serial from Matlab, Ive tried without that delay and it was the same. The problem were to a lot of Serial writes as you mentioned. I changed the logic code (removed those first lines of code before first if condition in loop and moved them inside if condition) so now its working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Rotem i removed those lines of code before if (Serial.available() > 0) and moved them inside so now it wont print pins state all time but only when i need them. Thank you for your help. It works fine with  fprintf(arduino,'%i',d); now.

Comment: @ASTeam sorry, I didn't mean why is delay there, I mean what is delay. I can't find the documentation of it in MATLAB.

Comment: @AnderBiguri my mistake, I wrote the code from my phone sorry, so i guess it came from Arduino syntax :/, its pause(3) not delay(3).

Comment: You need to create a timer, remove all your Serial.printf to MATLAB and just print times. If you do that, you can easily see what chunck of the code takes longest